# Connecting two different networks through wifi routers

Tags: linux, networking, routing, wlan, lan

I am trying to connect two different networks by using the following layout:

[image]

On the network 1 I have a computer/laptop with ip address 10.0.0.2/24 connected by Ethernet interface (eth0) through a Linux Router1 with ip 10.0.0.1. With the IP forward enabled on the Linux Router1, I am enable to forward packages from Computer1 to the Linux Router2 (I am able to ping Router2 from Computer1).
I am also able to perform the inverse route from Computer2 to Router1 by using the Linux Router2 that also forwards network packages.
But what I am trying to achieve is to establish communication between Computer1 and Computer2 in that network.

I would like, for example, to ping Computer2 from Computer1 and vice-versa. 
How can I do that by using Linux configurations (iptables, route tables, etc)??

Comment: Whatever else might be wrong, the picture shows two different IP networks used by the routers: 192.168.0.0/24 and 192.168.1.0/24 for their *direct* communication, while this should be a single network. Please explain this [in the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/666340/edit) first.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with the routing you've provided. (At least, not unless you're going to include all the needless complexity of proxy arp.)

Perhaps there's a typo in the router addresses and they are actually sharing a subnet, but as shown you do not have a route between the routers 192.168.0.1/24 and 192.168.1.1/24. Either change the subnet mask to /23 or put the routers in the same /24 subnet, such as 192.168.1.x/24

Having fixed that, all your devices on 10.0.0.x/24 will need a route to 10.0.1.x/24 via 10.0.0.1 and vice versa. Your routers will each need a route to the distant 10.* network via the opposite router.

Answer (score 0):

The short version is that router1 most likely doesn't know about `10.0.1.0\24` and router2 doesn't know about `10.0.0.0\24`.  So you need to put a static route on router1 and router2 that tells them where to send packets for the network they don't already know about.

It looks like computer1 already knows to send all everything it doesn't already know about to router1 and computer2 will likewise send everything it doesn't know about to router2.

You can use the command:

```
ip route add ...
```

You need to tell router1 to send all traffic for `10.0.1.0\24` to router2 (192.168.1.1 on your diagram).

You need to tell router2 to send all traffic for `10.0.0.0\24` to router1 (192.168.0.1 on your diagram)